# Read files into variable using then pass to delete call

Tags: bash

I am trying read all the files from list into a variable `line` using `bash` . After there are read into the variable they are passed to a delete call. The files appear to be read line (as I can see them with the `echo`) by line into the variable, but the delete call is not removing them and I do not know why? Thank you :).

**list**

```
overall.html
file1.bam
file2.bam
file1.vcf.gz
file2.vcf.gz
```

**Bash**

```
while read line; do
   echo $line
done < /home/cmccabe/list
wget --user=xxx --password=xxx --xxx --method=DELETE \
xxxx://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/$line
```

edit

```
while read line; do
   echo $line
   /home/cmccabe/list
   wget --user=xxx --password=xxx --xxx --method=DELETE \
   xxxx://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/$line
done
```

Comment: Your `wget` should be inside your `while` loop.

Comment: @JNevill is the edit `bash` correct?  Thank you :).

Comment: `done < /home/cmccabe/list` was correct, you just needed to move `wget ...` inside the loop. Everything else was fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to drag this out of the comments. Your script should be:

```
while read line; do
   echo $line   
   wget --user=xxx --password=xxx --xxx --method=DELETE \
   xxxx://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xx/xxxx/$line
done < /home/cmccabe/list
```

With the `wget` inside the loop. Essentially, every record in your file is assigned to variable `$line`, then in the next loop that is overwritten with the next record, so you have to do your `wget` before it's overwritten with the next record.

Furthermore, because a `read line` is processed in a subshell, your `$line` variable will be empty once the `while` loop is `done`. So running your `wget` outside the loop will result in a url that will be missing the file name at the end.

Comment: Thank you both and the explanation helps me learn and understand well :)